# How to verify if file is according to mask in PHP without reading filename from disk

Tags: php, pattern-matching, filenames, wildcard

I have a list of file names(I already have the filelist let's say in a text file). I want to process this list in the following way:

- filenames of type /dirX/subdirX/*/*.ext will be written in a new file
- all the other filenames will be written in a separate file.

Is there any option to verify if a filename corresponds to a mask, without reading the file name from disk?(by filename I mean a simple string). I would like to know if there is such a function that don't require disk access. I know regex could be an workaround but I'd like to have something from php.

Comment: I'm not SURE if wildcards work, but *.ext should return all the .ext files, if that's what you're asking. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: What's with the italicized slash? Also, I'm having trouble making sense of your question. If you are checking file paths strictly from a text file, then you would never need disk access. Do you have any code written you could show us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need [`fnmatch()`](http://it.php.net/fnmatch) ?

You should post some sample data if you need further info.

Answer (score 1):

You could likely use [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/fnmatch) which is built for the task you are asking to solve.  If that is not quite suitable, perhaps [regular expressions](http://php.net/book.pcre) could be of use.

Clarifying what your *mask* consists of would likely help guide answers towards what you want.

Comment: I've accepted kemp answer. fnmatch is what i was looking for. thanks.